# PouchDB Index creation and maintenance

Tags: pouchdb

When you create an index in PouchDB for pouchdb-find does it maintain it (add, delete records etc) itself?  Or do you have to keep recreating the index before you run query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the PouchDb guide the answer is "yes", the index is maintained in the database as the guide points out that first use of an index is slow but subsequent use much faster.

There is more detail here: https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html